# Define Guard Sequence And What Are The Valid Guard Expressions?

Tags: erlang, expression, guard

I want to know Guard Sequence And What Are The Valid Guard Expressions in Erlang?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The questions seems a bit too broad. What does the documentation say? Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guard Sequences](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-sequences)

> A guard sequence is a sequence of guards, separated by semicolon (;).
> The guard sequence is true if at least one of the guards is true. (The
> remaining guards, if any, are not evaluated.)
>
> Guard1;...;GuardK

Example:

```
go(X,Y) when X==1;Y==2 ->
   io:format("Yes~n").
```

In the shell:

```
2> a:go(1, 2).
Yes
ok
3> a:go(1, 3).
Yes
ok
4> a:go(4, 2).
Yes
ok
5> a:go(4, 3).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                a:go(4,3) (a.erl, line 4)
```

So, a semi-colon is like `OR`.

> A guard is a sequence of guard expressions, separated by comma (,).
> The guard is true if all guard expressions evaluate to true.
>
> GuardExpr1,...,GuardExprN

Example:

```
go(X,Y,Z) when X==1,Y==2, is_atom(Z) ->
    io:format("Yes~n").
```

In the shell:

```
8> a:go(1, 3, a).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    a:go(1,3,a) (a.erl, line 4)
9> a:go(1, 2, a).
Yes
ok
```

So, a comma is like `AND`.

[Guard Expressions](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-expressions)

> The set of valid guard expressions is a subset of the set of valid
> Erlang expressions. The reason for restricting the set of valid
> expressions is that evaluation of a guard expression must be
> guaranteed to be free of side effects. Valid guard expressions are the
> following:
>
> ```
> Variables
> Constants (atoms, integer, floats, lists, tuples, records, binaries, and maps)
> Expressions that construct atoms, integer, floats, lists, tuples, records, binaries, and maps
> Expressions that update a map
> The record epxressions Expr#Name.Field and #Name.Field
> Calls to the BIFs specified in tables Type Test BIFs and Other BIFs Allowed in Guard Expressions
> Term comparisons
> Arithmetic expressions
> Boolean expressions
> Short-circuit expressions (andalso/orelse)
> ```
>
> **Type Test BIFs:**
>
> ```
>     is_atom/1
>     is_binary/1
>     is_bitstring/1
>     is_boolean/1
>     is_float/1
>     is_function/1
>     is_function/2
>     is_integer/1
>     is_list/1
>     is_map/1
>     is_number/1
>     is_pid/1
>     is_port/1
>     is_record/2
>     is_record/3
>     is_reference/1
>     is_tuple/1
> ```
>
> Notice that most type test BIFs have older equivalents, without the
> is_ prefix. These old BIFs are retained for backwards compatibility
> only and are not to be used in new code. They are also only allowed at
> top level. For example, they are not allowed in Boolean expressions in
> guards.
>
> **Other BIFs Allowed in Guard Expressions:**
>
> ```
> abs(Number)
> bit_size(Bitstring)
> byte_size(Bitstring)
> element(N, Tuple)
> float(Term)
> hd(List)
> length(List)
> map_get(Key, Map)
> map_size(Map)
> node()
> node(Pid|Ref|Port)
> round(Number)
> self()
> size(Tuple|Bitstring)
> tl(List)
> trunc(Number)
> tuple_size(Tuple)
> ```
>
> If an arithmetic expression, a Boolean expression, a short-circuit
> expression, or a call to a guard BIF fails (because of invalid
> arguments), the entire guard fails. If the guard was part of a guard
> sequence, the next guard in the sequence (that is, the guard following
> the next semicolon) is evaluated.

This:

> A guard sequence is a sequence of guards, separated by semicolon (;).

gives you this:

```
GuardSequence = Guard1;Guard2;Guard3
```

What is a `Guard`? This sentence:

> A guard is a sequence of guard expressions, separated by comma (,).

gives you this:

```
Guard1 = GuardExpr1, GuardExpr2, GuardExpr3
```

What's a `guard expression`?  This sentence:

> The set of valid guard expressions is...

gives you stuff like:

```
GuardExpr1 = (X==1)
GuardExpr2 = (Y==2)
GuardExpr3  = is_atom(Z)
```

Now, substitute the GuardExpr's into this line:

```
 Guard1 = GuardExpr1, GuardExpr2, GuardExpr3
```

giving you:

```
 Guard1 =   X==1, Y==2, is_atom(Z)
```

Now, substitute `Guard1` into this line:

```
 GuardSequence = Guard1;Guard2;Guard3
```

giving you:

```
 GuardSequence = X==1, Y==2, is_atom(Z)
```

If you also have a Guard2 and Guard3, and they look like this:

```
 Guard2 =  is_integer(X)
 Guard3 =  element(Y, Tuple)
```

then GuardSequence would look like this:

```
GuardSequence = X==1, Y==2, is_atom(Z); is_integer(X); element(Y, Tuple)
```

OKAY??!